# Is there a proper way to order the Nginx FastCGI section?

Tags: nginx, proxy

Ubuntu 16.04
nginx version: nginx/1.16.0
pHp7.2 with Pool config

Is there a proper way to order the FastCGI section of an nginx webserver behind a proxy? Do the fastcgi_param lines go before or after the includes. Does it matter?

```
  #-- Pass The PHP Scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
    #-- Get REal Ips from proxy
    set_real_ip_from        172.16.0.1;
    fastcgi_param           REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
    include                 denyips.conf;
    try_files               $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_param           HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm-mcfilez.sock;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param           PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/home/.sites/mcfilez/httpdocs/zecurity/anti-hammer.php";
    fastcgi_read_timeout    600s;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Appreciate the help.

**Updated order**

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    set_real_ip_from        172.16.0.1;
    include                 denyips.conf;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param           REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
    fastcgi_param           PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/home/.sites/mcfilez/httpdocs/zecurity/anti-hammer.php";
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param           HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm-mcfilez.sock;
    try_files               $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_read_timeout    600s;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Nginx statements are unaffected by order, although there are a few exceptions.

Specifically affecting the FastCGI section is that the `fastcgi_param` directive will silently overwrite the value of a parameter, for example, in:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

The above will leave the value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` as `$request_filename`, but no errors or warnings are generated.

The silent overwriting of parameters may become an issue when using the `include` directive, as the duplicates may be hidden in the nother file.

As a general rule, place specific `fastcgi_param` statements **after** the `include` statements.

Comment: How does the order look now?